# 6 volt DC power receptacle

Tags: power-supply, plug

I have a toy that takes 4 AA batteries that I would like to modify to take AC power. I googled and found plenty of AC to DC power supply cables with the small socketed end. I know I could get one of those and cut off the socket and strip the cables and either solder or clamp them to the contacts in the toy. I'd like to do something a bit more clean, and find the receptacle socket for that ubiquitous AC->DC power cord. So I could mount that on the outside of the toy and solder its leads to the battery terminals. My google searches have failed, probably because I don't know what I'm looking for.

Can someone give me the name of the component or a link to one?

Here's the power cable I've found in case I'm not describing it well. [https://www.amazon.com/ZJchao-Adapter-Precision-Pressure-Monitors/dp/B009SNJ0NS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009SNJ0NS)

Comment: Yes, you can. My dad has been doing this since I was 8 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something known as a *DC power jack*.  Go to any reputable distributor web site, like Mouser or DigiKey, and look around.

At the very least you have to know the outer diameter of the plug this receptacle is supposed to receive.  In some cases, there are different inner diameters for the same outer diameter.  But in most cases, just knowing the outer diameter is all you need.

You want one that is *chassis mounted*.  However, if you can't find a suitable one, then a PC mount version and a glob of hot glue is plan B.

### Added

I just looked at your link.  The description tells you the size of the plug directly.  That's what "5.5/2.1 mm" means.  The outer diameter is 5.5 mm, and the inner is 2.1 mm.  These things are usually named and sorted by outer diameter.  You therefore want a *5.5 mm DC power jack*.  Once you get to the details, you can see if a particular jack is compatible with a 2.1 mm inner diameter plug.

Answer (score 1):

An image search for [DC+power+jack+chassis+socket](https://www.google.ie/search?q=dc+power+jack+chassis+socket) returns the following.

[image]

I use my 0.5 mm drill-bit set to check the diameter of pin required.